# Define a custom AndroidManifest property to fastlane

Tags: android, gradle, fastlane

I have a custom variable on both `build.gradle` and `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
      manifestPlaceholders.myCustomProperty = "#"
   }
}
```

and

```
<meta-data
   android:name="CUSTOM_PROPERTY"
   android:value="${myCustomProperty} />
```

I want to define `myCustomProperty` in Fastfile. None of the following work:

```
gradle(
    task: "assemble"
    ...
    properties {
        "manifestPlaceholders.myCustomProperty" => "Value 1",
        "myCustomProperty" => "Value 2",
        "android.defaultConfig.manifestPlaceholders.myCustomProperty" => "Value 3"
    }
)
```

I always get `#` when using `myCustomProperty` in the app (after building it with Fastfile).

Comment: Have you been able to come up with something ?